# What exactly does the capture_memcache_keys flag do in the New Relic configuration yml?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, memcached, analytics, newrelic

In the New Relic configuration (in this case, the context is a Rails 3 application which utilizes memcache), there is a section with the following flag:

```
# If you're interested in capturing memcache keys as though they
# were SQL uncomment this flag. Note that this does increase
# overhead slightly on every memcached call, and can have security
# implications if your memcached keys are sensitive
# capture_memcache_keys: true
```

By default, is commented out.  The description is not particularly clear to me (due to already having retained some weeks work of data), and trying it both ways hasn't shown a difference I can discern.  Does this flag enable capturing of memcache tracing/capturing in general?  Or does it "lump" memcache queries in with SQL requests?

I would like to trace memcache, for sure, to see if it is operating properly, and at what speed, etc.  Should this flag be set to true, generally, in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to enable the capture_memcache_keys flag in order to capture memcache metrics in general. If a memcache client is found, the disable_memcache_instrumentation flag will automatically default to false (thus measuring memcache metrics). The capture_memcache_keys flag basically allows you the additional option to capture the unique memcache keys in SQL format, if so desired.

You can find more details on the New Relic Ruby agent configuration at https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration.